# Why are top level or-patterns not allowed in let bindings?

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

```rs
fn foo(ok: bool) -> Result<i32, i32> {
    if ok { Ok(0) } else { Err(0) }
}

fn main() {
    let Ok(x) | Err(x) = foo(true); // rust-analyzer error: top-level or-patterns are not allowed in `let` bindings

    if let Ok(x) | Err(x) = foo(true) { // rust-analyzer warn: irrefutable `if let` pattern
        println!("Working!");
    }
}
```

Or is this a rust-analyzer bug? I tried to Google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You should always look at what the *compiler* tells you to get the full picture (in this case you'll see that it suggests a fix for your code so that it will compile). Just looking at the errors in the tooltip or problem list in your IDE will only give you partial information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that top-level or-patterns aren't allowed is because [it would cause certain `macro_rules!` macros](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2535#issuecomment-418757466) to break. The pattern in a let expression should be matchable by a single `$p:pat`, but without requiring it to be parenthesized, a `$p:pat` would only consume the first part of the or-pattern.

Note that you can work around this easily, as the compiler suggests when you try this:

```
error: top-level or-patterns are not allowed in `let` bindings
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     let Ok(x) | Err(x) = foo(true);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ help: wrap the pattern in parentheses: `(Ok(x) | Err(x))`
```

Wrapping the or-expression in brackets fixes this, since now a bracket expression is the top-level expression:

```rust
let (Ok(x) | Err(x)) = foo(true);
```